# Where clause in eloquent relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models Student and Fees which has relations

- Student has many Fees
- Fees belongsTo Student

In `Student.php`

```
public function fees()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Fees::class, 'std_id');
}
```

In `Fees.php`

```
public function student(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class,'std_id');
}
```

Now I need to Find Fees for individual students. What should I do now?

In controller

```
$fees = Fees::with('student')->where('fees->student->id', '=', $request->id)->get();
```

it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$student_fees = Student::find($request->id)->fees;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get students with fees then you can do it this way

```
$students = Student::with('fees')->where('std_id','=',$request->id)->get(); //also can get it by single instance using ->first();
```

Modified code

```
$fees = Fees::with('student')->where('std_id', '=', $request->id)->get();
```

Comment: it creates another problem.  That's why I find the solution in that way

Comment: can you explain further?

Comment: updated my comment above maybe that will help you